# Conditional split Lists or Arrays (or get Sublist etc)

Tags: c#, arrays, performance, list, linq

what is the best way to create (conditional) sub-Lists/Arrays out of existing ones?

My tests So far are only very basic. I would like to get a better understanding about the background logic both for Lists and Arrays and if there are any better (more performant) ways to handle this.

```
List<TestClass> list = Enumerable.Range(0, 10_000_000).Select(l => new TestClass()).ToList();
Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
stopwatch.Start();

List<TestClass> list2 = list.Where(l => l.PickMe).ToList(); // 1

stopwatch.Stop();
Debug.WriteLine(stopwatch.ElapsedTicks);
stopwatch.Restart();

List<TestClass> list3 = new List<TestClass>(list.Count);
foreach(TestClass test in list.Where(l => l.PickMe))
{
    list3.Add(test); // 2
}

stopwatch.Stop();
Debug.WriteLine(stopwatch.ElapsedTicks);
stopwatch.Restart();

List<TestClass> list4 = new List<TestClass>(list);
list4.RemoveAll(l => !l.PickMe); // 3

stopwatch.Stop();
Debug.WriteLine(stopwatch.ElapsedTicks);
```

Result:

```
894168
767723
608211
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "Better understanding and [...] better ways" seems pretty broad and probably a bit opinion-based. Thus it doesn´t fit SOs rules for what is on- and off-topic very well. Could you please be a bit more specific on what you don´t understand and where you have difficulties? What do you actually want to *achieve* by this code? Why do you bother for performance if this is just a test for understanding?

Comment: `10_000_000` ? I have an hard time with this [mcve]. Will a List<bool> be enought to illustrate the  issue ?

Comment: what's `10_000_000`? that's not a number at all? does your posted code compiles?

Comment: `newListSplit= source.where().ToList();` bench mark a simple select like this. you don't have to add if you already have filter with where.

Comment: @Rahul thats C# 7 [Literal improvements](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/03/09/new-features-in-c-7-0/). _C# 7.0 allows underscore to occur as a digit separator inside number literals. You can put them wherever you want between digits, to improve readability. They have no effect on the value._

Comment: Ah!! I see ... thanks @Magnetron

Comment: You may want to look at how the new Span<T> works with Arrays and see if that fits your needs.

Comment: In general, indexing into `List` is faster than enumerating them. Try a `for` loop and an `if` to add selected members to another `List`.

Comment: @HimBromBeere: Thank you for your feedback. This code is part of a "high-performant" (1-10ms) update cycle, where i need to find and process changed values in a large List of Variables (not primitive values, but more complex classes). So I start with a List, select all unresolved changes and forward those in a new created sub-List. I assume things like pre-alloc capacity will help, but I'm curious if there are any more tricks/tipps to further improve this

Comment: Actually  *"better understanding about the background logic both for Lists and Arrays"* and *"any better (more performant) ways to handle this"* are actually two seperate questions. This is why I still consider this question too broad. Post a *single* question please. Apart from this at least the first part of that question is quite unspecific: what *exactly* don´t you understand? Where do you have difficulties?

Comment: @HimBromBeere: Probably a justified objection ;) So I found different ways to create such a "sublist", but as I want to optimize the performance, I wanted to understand why `.Where().ToList()`is slower than `new List() + .RemoveAll()`. Or is my way of measuring time flawed? Is it better to create a global second list and instead use `.Clear(), .AddRange()` ? Are there any better Collections like the mentioned `Span<T>` (Thank you @Flydog57, I will check this later!)? Therefore the more unspecific question...(sorry)

Comment: Maybe because of some initialization. Hard to guess, though. But you should definitly optimize your code **only** if you certainly *know* that your code needs to be optimized, which is when you *measured* it and found out its a **bottleneck**. Usually a few nano-seconds aren´t worth the afford unless executed some billions of times. In particular that leads to less easy to understand and less manitainable code

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to the source code for your examples:

- Where - https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,312
- ToList - https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,329
- Add - https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,220
- RemoveAll - https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,842

Calling `ToList` will create a new list from the provided `IEnumerable<TSource>`.      There isn't any real difference between `Where + ToList` and `Where + Add` - both are basically doing same thing.

The `RemoveAll` may be slightly faster in some cases because it tries to reuse the source list by removing the items in place that do not match the clause, and then freeing the remainder of the internal array. However, this could be slower for other scenarios.

I doubt there is any clear winner for all scenarios, and the differences are probably so negligible that it is likely best to write code that is simplest to read and maintain than to worry about the internals of any of these approaches.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and the provided links! The only reason I tested `Where + Add` was to pre-define an initial capacity of the List. I will take a look at the source code to understand the background mechanics a little bit better. Tt seems that at pre-defining the capacity is helping and there seem to be some performance differences for Lists between adding/removing at the end/middle...and there are also other classes like `Span<T>` or `LinkedList<T>`. But it seems you are right that there is no general "winner" ;)